# Turn a exponential horizontal asymptotic into php

Tags: php, math, formula, exponential

So i have this formula that i want to use in a PHP project.
The problem i'm having is that i lack the knowlege in PHP to make it work. I only get "Parse error: syntax error" when i try to use it. And as i said, i belive it is because i dont know how to reformat it for PHP.

I have been reading up on this for quite awhile now, on both google and stackoverflow, but i have yet to find a solution.

So the formula i want to use, or turn into a function is;
X = 80-79*1.02^(-(X-1)). But how do i make use of it in PHP?

I appreciate your your help.

Comment: is `1,02` supposed to be a decimal? `1.02`?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. 1.02, i will edit that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pow()` instead of `^` to raise to a power:

```
echo pow(80 - 79 * 1.02, -($X - 1));
```

Or a simple function:

```
function my_func($X) {
    return pow(80 - 79 * 1.02, -($X - 1));
}

echo my_func(0);
```

The exponentiation operator `**` was introduced in PHP 5.6.0:

```
echo 80 - 79 * 1.02 ** -($X - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `pow` function in PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php

Or, power operator `**`:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

example: `2^8` should be `2**8`

Comment: I will have to read up on this, thankns. 
I just quickly tried using the ** operator tho, and i still got the same error. 

Atleast now i have something to read up on and test out!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot AbraCadaver! 
The function you gave me will not work as it does the calculations in a faulty way. But i rewrote it quickly and it works like a charm!
I will obviusly change the var names, but here is how it looks.

```
function my_func($X) {
    $y = -($X - 1);
    $y2 = pow(1.02, $y);
    $y3 = 79 * $y2;
    $y4 = 80 - $y3;

    return $y4;
}
```

Comment: Not the formula I gave you, the formula YOU GAVE US...  Basic math `return 80 - (79 * pow(1.02, -($X - 1)));`

Comment: Ment to say the function, i had to break up the calculation in parts to get the correct outcome of my formula. Thanks alot for your help tho, i appreciate it alot.